# Can't scrape title from some urls using Python's BeasutifulSoup4 / extraction

Tags: python, extract

I have two simple python scripts to scrape the title, main image, description from a url. One uses extraction and the other uses BeautifulSoup4. Both work great with most urls (e.g. http://nytimes.com). But in both cases there are some urls that don't work: namely http://latimes.com which is odd since it's such a big site. I made two different scripts to maybe confirm the problem wasn't coming from the library.

What am I missing? Could someone help me figure out how why I'm not getting anything back?

---

Script no. 1:

```
import extraction, requests
ext = extraction.Extractor()

print('Enter url:')
url = input() 
x = ext.extract(requests.get(url).text, source_url=url)

print(x.title)
print(x.url)
print(x.description)
```

Result from script no. 1:

[image]

---

Script no. 2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

print('Enter url:')
url = input()

source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

title = soup.find("meta", property="og:title")["content"]
typeof = soup.find("meta", property="og:type")["content"]
image = soup.find("meta", property="og:image")["content"]
url = soup.find("meta", property="og:url")["content"]
summary = soup.find("meta", property="og:description")["content"]

print(title)
print(typeof)
print(image)
print(url)
print(summary)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this web is waiting for an adequate 'User-agent' ?

Answer (score 1):

Errors contain tonnes of information, but you have to take a second to interpret them correctly.

Script 1: The request could not be satisfied. Ergo, something goes wrong with the request. Try:

```
import extraction
import requests
ext = extraction.Extractor()

print('Enter url:')
url = input() 

r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code != 200: # check if request is _not_ OK
    print(f"Error {r.status_code} when requesting {url}!")
    return

x = ext.extract(, source_url=url)

print(x.title)
print(x.url)
print(x.description)
```

Same issue with script 2. If Apparently `soup.find("meta", property="og:title")` returns `None`, thus the `[]` term errors out. So go back and print `soup`, to see if the script is still okay there.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Appreciate it!